# Saving multiple images and naming them indvidually?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a region, in a loop, save the screenshots to a folder and rename them so they don't overwrite each other.

I'm wanting a folder full of images with unique names, ideally timestamps but I've not figured that out at all yet so I'm using a counter for now.

```
import pyautogui as py

                    for image in image_list:
                        screenshot = py.screenshot(region=(x,y,w,h)
                        save_path = r'C:\'
                        count = count + 1
                        name_of_file = count
                        completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".png")
                        screenshot.save(completeName)
```

Is giving me this error;

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".png")
```

I've tried:

- Wrapping `name_of_file+` with `str`: `completeName = os.path.join(save_path, (str(name_of_file+".png")))`

But I get the same error message.

I tried:

- swapping the `+` for a `,`
- wrapping everything `completeName = os.path.join(str(save_path), (str(name_of_file,".png")))`

And those gave me a different error message: `TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, int found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that it your variable is not a float therefore:

```
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".png")
```

should read:

```
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, str(name_of_file)+".png")
```

Consider using pathlib to construct paths in your script. This is a more robust way that using `r"C:\"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with file_name_<>.png like-
(This format works on cv2.write. Hopefully should work in pyautogui too)

```
count = 0


completeName = "<save_path>/screenshot_%d.png" %count
count = count + 1
screenshot.save(completename)
```